# Wildfly 10. logging.properties

Tags: log4j, wildfly-10

Is there a way to have a static logging.properties or an equivalent to have the log4j properties defined. It is because to seperate out the properties file instead of defining each property in standalone.xml file to avoid the main xml not to be disturbed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Are you not wanting to use the logging subsystem?

Comment: As per this link [https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-Whyistherea%7B%7Blogging.properties%7D%7Dfile%3F], it says logging.properties file will be obverriden.

Need similar way to have the properties defined instead of defining in the standalone.xml or equivalent file

Comment: Are you trying to have properties written to the `logging.properties` file?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, yes, we need to have the properties to be written to **logging.properties** file, but not to XML file which is common and will have all information

Comment: This is not currently possibly unfortunately. You can use properties in the logging subsystem, but those will not be written to the `logging.properties` file. There are some details on https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-157.